# How to properly rotate vector keeping circular (not ellipse) shape in openlayers-3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm new in maping apps. I already get the vector rotation calculating the center and final point on a x-y plane doing a simple trigonometric ecuation using an external script (I want to solve it on server side) and then using the linestring feature I can draw the line on the map. The issue is than when the vector is on 90 or 270 degrees, its module is longer than when it is at 0 or 180. I know than lat and long coordinates does not have the same scale, so my question is:
 how can I perform the points calculation in server-side and provide them as coords to the javascript side to properly draw a shape and rotate it without distortion?

lets take a look to the picture.
I have been trying with a triangle and a line shape.
As you can see, all of them can rotate but they don't keep same ratio.
Any help would be great for me to continue working on this.
[achieved so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNEwN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I got it working ... I know this is not a very elegant solution but at least it is working for me.
So , since lat and lon are not a lineal relation (this is only true near the ecuador) Yo can not use a simple trigonometric function to represent poligons on the map.
What I did is to manually add a corrector factor to one of the triangle side.
If you need some help jut let me know.
Regards,
Leandro.